# Creating an anaconda environment through pycharm gives HTTP error

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

so I've recently fresh installed pycharm and anaconda, and in attempting to setup a file in pycharm using a new conda environment I get this error:

> Solving environment: ...working... failed
>
> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url
>   https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors
>   are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>
> If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please
>   file a support request with your network engineering team.
>
> SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect
>   to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))

The strange thing is that when I setup an anaconda environment manually through it's own GUI and reference to it in pycharm it seems to work fine. Does anyone have any ideas as to why pycharm throws that error but anaconda itself doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when using google-cloud services in a new conda environment.
Your system is complaining for not having any SSL module.

The solution is pretty simple.
`pip install pyopenssl`

if you are running inside Anaconda be sure to use pip within the environment concerned, by calling beforehand :
`conda activate concerned_env`